# How can I get UserSession in baseController?

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to get UserSession.

```
public abstract class BaseController : ServiceStackController<CustomUserSession>
{
    public AuthService AuthService { get; set; } // NOT Autowired -Problem 1
    public BaseController()
    {
        //this.ControllerContext = null  -Problem 2
        //UserSession   'UserSession' threw an exception of type System.NullReferenceException' -Problem 3

        if (!this.ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But there are 3 problems as you can see.
Why I need this? I want to apply user specific css in _Layout.cshtml.

How can I get current User Session in Controller?

Answer (score 1):

I had a null UserSession aswell, solved it by adding the following code to the Configure method in AppHost:

```
    //Set MVC to use the same Funq IOC as ServiceStack
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
    ServiceStackController.CatchAllController = reqCtx => container.TryResolve<HomeController>();
```

Not sure about the AuthService autowiring, maybe the above will solve that too